# Why my WSO2 APIM APIKeyValidator responds with Erro?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am building an cluster with 2 WSO2 APIM All-in-One distributions. So at this point I have the APACHE as front end of my cluster and the others 2 APIM nodes shared the <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server.
The problem now is the APIKeyValidator. After published and subscribed in test API, when I am try to consume an operation, I am receiving the message:

```
{
  "fault": {
    "code": 900900,
    "message": "Unclassified Authentication Failure",
    "description": "Resource forbidden"
  }
}
```

My carbon log gave me the follow lines:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,476] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator} -  Received Token 44ce0123-2815-3a9c-8acf-9e12bc5ae2a6 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,476] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator} -  Default Version API invoked {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,476] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator} -  Removing Authorization header from headers {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,477] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator} -  Found resource in Cache for key: /apis/operadoras/3.0.0/3.0.0/operadoras:GET {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,477] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator} -  Matching resource is: /operadoras {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,477] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient} -  KeyValidation request from gateway to keymanager via web service call for:/apis/operadoras/3.0.0 with ID: urn:uuid:f345252f-24f5-48e6-a6e2-7d2154f6177d at [2020.12.09 11:19:53,477 BRT] {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,489] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService} -  KeyValidation request from gateway: requestTime= [2020.12.09 11:19:53,489 BRT] , for:/apis/operadoras/3.0.0 with accessToken=44ce0123-2815-3a9c-8acf-9e12bc5ae2a6 , transactionId= {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,489] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService} -  Before calling Validate Token method... {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,489] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService} -  **State after calling validateToken ... true** {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,491] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService} -  **State after calling validateSubscription... true** {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,492] **ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Invalid tenant domain null** {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:147)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:232)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException: Invalid tenant domain null**
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException.error(IdentityRuntimeException.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityTenantUtil.getTenantId(IdentityTenantUtil.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.JDBCScopeValidator.getTenantId(JDBCScopeValidator.java:294)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.JDBCScopeValidator.validateScope(JDBCScopeValidator.java:150)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler.validateScopes(DefaultKeyValidationHandler.java:180)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService.validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:188)
        ... 59 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,496] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  Call to Key Manager : API call failed reason=API_authentication_failure transactionId=urn:uuid:f345252f-24f5-48e6-a6e2-7d2154f6177d with userAgent=PostmanRuntime/7.26.8 for requestURI=/apis/operadoras/3.0.0/operadoras at time=Wed Dec 09 11:19:53 BRT 2020 from clientIP=10.19.52.80, elapsedTimeInMilliseconds=0 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-09 11:19:53,496] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Resource forbidden
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.WSAPIKeyDataStore.getAPIKeyData(WSAPIKeyDataStore.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.doGetKeyValidationInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:323)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getKeyValidationInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:255)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:206)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient.getAPIKeyData(APIKeyValidatorClient.java:123)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.WSAPIKeyDataStore.getAPIKeyData(WSAPIKeyDataStore.java:48)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid tenant domain null
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:381)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:456)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.validator.APIKeyValidationServiceStub.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceStub.java:531)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient.getAPIKeyData(APIKeyValidatorClient.java:110)
        ... 19 more
```

I don´t find any information that could help me to deal with this issue...
Have any one an idea?
**UPDATE**: After  a good investigation I have discovered that the problem
 happens only when we configure scopes. If we don´t use scopes The servers request have no problem.
**UPDATE 2**: After turn on the *log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2=DEBU*G in the *log4j.properties*, I had discovery that, the scopes and tenants are created and available for resources but the resource has one more ***'/3.0.0'*** (version).

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-11 12:04:22,320] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.DefaultOAuth2TokenValidator} -  There is no scope validator registered for subscriber_DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION@carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.DefaultOAuth2TokenValidator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-11 12:04:22,322] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenManagementDAOImpl} -  Retrieving tenant and scope for resource: /apis/myapi/3.0.0/3.0.0/info:GET {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenManagementDAOImpl}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-11 12:04:22,324] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenManagementDAOImpl} -  Found tenant id: -1234 and scope: SC_OPERADORAS_R for resource: /apis/myapi/3.0.0/3.0.0/info:GET {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenManagementDAOImpl}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-11 12:04:22,325] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Invalid tenant domain null {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Na
```

Comment: Are the nodes sharing the same database in the config? Where is the key manager configuration of the nodes pointing to? What happens when you send the request directly to the nodes instead of the load balancer, are both nodes responding the same way?

Comment: Yes the nodes are sharing the same database. I am using an All-in-one deployment Active-Active so the Key managers are in the  instances. Send requestes directly to Nodes make the seme problems happens....